# Why do contact lens work when they're inside out?

Tags: optics, lenses

They're uncomfortable, but they still correct vision. I think there is probably a simple physics explanation for this, but I haven't been able to find one by thinking/googling around.

Comment: what do you mean by "inside out" in this context?

Comment: Does the explanation of meniscus lenses on wikipedia help <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens#Types_of_simple_lenses>?

Comment: He means that the inside of the lens faces outwards. "Inside" means the side that goes "in" towards the eye normally; "outside" is the outward oriented world.

Comment: @AnoE thank you, yes this is what I mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key mechanical property that enables the optical function of the lens is that its thickness varies from the center to the edge. That doesn't change.

Comment: A meniscus lens with constant nonzero thickness still has nonzero optical power.

Comment: @TLW Constant thickness also doesn't change when you flip the lens inside out.

Comment: Correct, however that is besides the point. Non-constant thickness is not "[t]he key mechanical property that enables the optical function of the lens".